# Where is the best way to approach hallway usability testing?

Tags: usability-testing, user-research

I found [UserTesting.com](https://www.usertesting.com) but it costs $40 per person which is super expensive. I want to test if I am communicating the correct message to users on our site. Where is a good place to do some hallway testing? Or does it have to be in-person?

Comment: I found this useful, Steve Krug doing a simple usability test:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QckIzHC99Xc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Assumptions

- it's **just a message to test**, e.g. a tagline on your site that explains
  what the site/product is about, not a bunch of features at once
- $40 is too much for that (I agree) but **I guess $3 would be ok**
- **personal interview preferred over anonymous test** (at least this is my preference - so much richer feedback)

## Try Starbucks testing*

Here is how it works:

- **Go to a coffee house** or similar place where people spend some time
- **Find people** that could be users of your site
- Approach them **right after they bought a coffee** and **ask them**:
  "*You just bought a coffee. Can I buy you a muffin and get two minutes of your time for a quick feedback on my website?*"
- Ask your questions and **make them talk as much as possible** without influencing them
- Get inspired by the answers and **find out if your message works**

The last question, especially if the message/site didn't work well, is to explain the intention and ask them what they would have understood better. But only do this as the last thing, don't get into a debate take the comment with a grain of salt.

---

*I call this Starbucks testing because it works especially well in coffee houses where people are relaxed and spending some leisure time. Often they're open to talk. It might be different in other countries or cultures. I think key success factors are that they get a little reward for their time investment and to make them understand that you won't be trying to sell something.

If you want to learn more about user testing I'd suggest [Rocket surgery made easy](http://www.sensible.com/rsme.html) by Steve Krug - an enjoyable and entertaining read.

Answer (score 5):

If you're new to usability testing, and want to do something cheap and effective, I would recommend that you read [Rocket Surgery Made Easy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321657292) by Steve Krug

It's a very good introduction to running cheap in-person usability tests. Has the added bonus of being quite a thin book too. I'm sure your local library could help find a copy if you don't want to buy one.

Answer (score 4):

I have never used them and I don't know precisely how much analysis usertesting.com provides but you have to realize that setting a test up involves some real work and having a platform to do it so quickly seems very valuable. The users themselves also have to spend time testing your website and deserve a reward so that $40 is actually super cheap. In fact, simply recruiting users through a consumer panel with some minimal targeting (i.e. including the incentive but without the cost of the test/interview/recording) cost more than that where I am now. Why would you think usability testing should be virtually cost-free and you could get useful feedback from multiple people without effort?

Regarding hallway usability testing, the whole point is to quickly test a product with whoever you can find in the hallway (hence the name), typically colleagues, perhaps friends or family. The idea is to compromise on the quality of the sample to be able to gain some quick feedback even if a regular usability test is not practical for you. It does not *have* to be anything but it's usually in-person, if only because looking for actual users and setting up a remote usability test does in fact require more effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try usabilityhub's preference test, or 5-second test (can't really say without knowing more about your project) if you want to gauge messaging. If you complete other tests on the site, you get karma points, which you can then use to fund your own tests. Awesome service.